# Are these hex color codes inside square brackets some standard format?

Tags: html, colors, formatting, format, hex

I have received a dataset containing some HTML-like data cells like the following:

```
<span style="font-family: Arial; white-space: pre;">
[#FFFF00#202030]      [#202030#FFFFFF]Word1[#FFFFFF#202030]:[#202030#FFFFFFui]Word2 etc
</span>
```

I suppose the hex codes in brackets correspond to text & background color (probably background first). But is it some standard format, in HTML or other language? Any idea what the suffix `ui` means inside the square brackets?

Comment: it's not standard html or css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have recieved this code which just shows information between `<Span></Span>` tag. It means nothing. It will just display as it is.

In style Information `white-space: pre;` it means preformatted text.

The information you recieved like `[#FFFF00]` is the hex color code of variant yellow.

However, I am not sure though it could be some IDE plugin code. check the reference link for example :

https://forum.smallgiantgames.com/t/how-do-i-put-colorful-writing-in-chat/3700/23